# Get all user details from facebook event with field expansion

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-field-expansion

I want to get all the user details from an event using the field expansion.

In pseudo code i think it should be something like this.

GET https://graph.facebook.com//attending.user(name,id,picture)

I can't get this to work (testing this in the graph explorer) Don't know if this is even possible.

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a url like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/EVENTID/?fields=attending.fields(id,name,picture)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't found the facebook documentation very clear for me.

So you select the field attending ( all the users) and then you take the fields id, name and picture from every user that has got a rsvp status of attending?

Comment: Yes. I tested this on one of my page's events. You can build queries like this in the Graph API explorer. Click on the `+ ...` under the node, and popups will show you all the different options to add (and the correct syntax).